# Link another structure in C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I am trying to do this data stucture in C. Connect another structure to another structure. Like this:

```
struct room
{
 int roomnumber;
 struct room * nextRoom;
 struct person * personList;
}*top=NULL,*temp=NULL,top1;

struct person
{
 int personnumber;
 struct person *next;
}*node=NULL,temp1;
```

Struct room has a pointer to struct person. I am having a hard time on connecting it to another struct. Is this correct?

Here is my function

```
void insert()
{
    int val;
    printf("enter value: ");
    scanf("%d",&val);
    newnode=create_node(val);
    if(top->personList==NULL)
    {
        top->personList=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        node->next=newnode;
        node=newnode;


    }
}
```

Insert a person to the room. Room is like created already. `create_node()` is the one who does the `malloc()`

Comment: `top` starts off as NULL so doing `top->` is dangerous unless you point it at something earlier.

Comment: so I should do some condition like. If top == NULL?

Comment: Show `create_node` function, please.

Comment: Yes, although, it depends on exactly what you want `top` to represent vs. `top1` for example.

Comment: Ok. Is the insert function connecting the nodes part is correct?

Comment: You should also try to avoid using globals when you can.  Also, name them in a manner that indicates they are global (e.g. - capitalize first letter, prepend g, etc.).

Comment: @EyamSaye Not quite.  It looks like you are using `node` to track the end of the personList for fast appending, but you also need to set `node = newnode;` when you set `top->personList=newnode;`.  You also really need to pick better descriptive names if these are going globals and used this way. Instead of `node` use something like `LastInList`.

Comment: I'd also recommend you try writing a version of your program that uses no globals at all.  Instead, declare your variables in main and pass the necessary information as parameters to your functions to operate on them.

Comment: @jschultz410 Right, got random name variables because of this part connecting nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that doesn't use globals, which makes your functions much more general and reusable:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct person
{
  int            personNumber;

  struct person *next;

} person;  /* NOTE: this is a typedef, not a global declaration like you did */

typedef struct room
{
  int          roomNumber;
  person      *personList;
  person      *lastInList;

  struct room *nextRoom;

} room;  /* NOTE: this is a typedef, not a global declaration like you did */

person *create_person(int val)
{
  person *ret = calloc(1, sizeof(*ret));

  if (ret)
  {
    ret->personNumber = val;
    ret->next         = NULL;
  }

  return ret;
}

int room_insert(room *r, int val)
{
  person *p = create_person(val);

  if (NULL == p)
    return -1;

  if (NULL != r->personList)
    r->lastInList->next = p;

  else
    r->personList = p;

  r->lastInList = p;

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  room    my_room       = { 0 };  /* important! initializes pointers to NULL */
  room    my_other_room = { 0 };  /* important! initializes pointers to NULL */
  person *p;

  room_insert(&my_room, 5);
  room_insert(&my_other_room, -5);

  room_insert(&my_room, 10);
  room_insert(&my_other_room, -10);

  room_insert(&my_room, 15);    
  room_insert(&my_other_room, -15);

  for (p = my_room.personList; p; p = p->next)
    printf("%d\n", p->personNumber);

  for (p = my_other_room.personList; p; p = p->next)
    printf("%d\n", p->personNumber);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of calloc and malloc?

Comment: @EyamSaye calloc zeros all the bytes of allocated memory while malloc may leave it as random junk.

Comment: why did you add a *person lastInList in the structure room?

Comment: why did you add a *person lastInList in the structure room?

Comment: @EyamSaye Just so that I could quickly append new persons to the end of the list without linearly running through it to the end.  I really only added that because your code seemed to be doing something like that with `node`.  It really isn't necessary unless you expect to have very long lists.

Comment: Lets say I added more info to struct person, like char name[20]. If I want to change the name of a specific person, only the name, Is it hard to do?

Comment: No, just get a pointer to that person and modify the contents of that array as you want.

Comment: Can I just point to the person and strcpy pointer->name, newname?

Comment: @EyamSaye Basically, yes.  Although, you should prefer to use `strncpy` because `name` is a fixed size array.